# CLOUD DEPLOYMENT MANAGER: Internal Load Balancer create issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am using the following to try and create an internal load balancer via Deployment Manager using the following code

```
- name:  {{ env["name"] }}-port389-healthcheck
type: compute.v1.healthChecks
properties:
    type: tcp
    tcpHealthCheck: {
    port: 389
    }

- name: {{ env["name"] }}-port389-backend-service
type: compute.beta.backendService
properties:
    healthChecks:
    - $(ref.{{ env["name"] }}-port389-healthcheck.selfLink)
    backends:
    - group: $(ref.{{ env['name'] }}-master-instance-groups-managed.instanceGroup)
    - group: $(ref.{{ env['name'] }}-slave-instance-groups-managed.instanceGroup)
    protocol: TCP
    region: {{ properties['region'] }}
    loadBalancingScheme: INTERNAL

- name: {{ env["name"] }}-port389-forwarding-rule
type: compute.beta.forwardingRule
properties:
    loadBalancingScheme: INTERNAL
    ports: 
    - 389
    network: default
    region: {{ properties["region"] }}
    backendService: $(ref.{{ env["name"] }}-port389-backend-service.selfLink)
```

It errrors when run with the following

```
Waiting for create operation-1478651694403-540d36cfdcdb9-cba25532-08697daf...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.deployment-manager.deployments.create) Error in Operation operation-1478651694403-540d36cfdcdb9-cba25532-08697daf:
errors:
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
location: /deployments/forgerock/resources/forgerock-frontend-port389-backend-service-us-central1
message: 'Unexpected response from resource of type compute.beta.backendService:
    400 {"code":400,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"Invalid value for field
    ''resource.loadBalancingScheme'': ''INTERNAL''. Load balancing scheme must be
    external for a global backend service.","reason":"invalid"}],"message":"Invalid
    value for field ''resource.loadBalancingScheme'': ''INTERNAL''. Load balancing
    scheme must be external for a global backend service.","statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/carbide-tenure-557/global/backendServices"}'
```

It would appear to be creating using the `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/carbide-tenure-557/global/backendServices` instead of `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/carbide-tenure-557/backendServices`

I know this is beta functionality, but trying to develop this solution using `GDM` instead of a mixture of `gcloud` commands and `GDM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For type instead of `type: compute.beta.backendService` use:

**`type: compute.v1.regionBackendService`**

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did try this a couple of weeks ago when I found it in the `Beta` Documentation and it still failed, but I was using  `compute.beta.regionBackendService`